# Passing a DirichletBC to a BoundaryCondition vector

Tags: c++, swig, finite-element-analysis

I'm using the FEniCS package to do some FEM. I'm trying to push a DirichletBC instance into a vector of type `const BoundaryCondition*`. Currently I've got

```
std::vector<const BoundaryCondition*> bcs;
DirichletBC bcl(V0, c, left);
bcs.push_back(&bcl)
```

Even though this is done in an example I've seen, I get the error

```
no matching function for call to
std::vector<const dolfin::BoundaryCondition*>::push_back(dolfin::DirichletBC&)
```

Having a look through the dolfin library files I see a SWIG typemap .i file that seems to allow this kind of behaviour, do I use this, or have I missed something?

Comment: why would you want to put the pointer to a local stack variable in your vector? how about `DirichletBC* bcl=new DirichletBC(V0, c, left); bcs.push_back(bcl)`?

Comment: Are you sure that `DirichletBC` inherits publicly from `BoundaryCondition`? It seems that the compiler is not able to find a conversion from `DirichletBC` to `BoundaryCondition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it took me so long to just try making the vector of type DirichletBC* instead. Now I have

`std::vector<const DirichletBC*> bcs;
DirichletBC bcl(V0, c, left);
bcs.push_back(&bcl)`

and it works fine.